# To access QML component in C++ backend

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent, qqmlapplicationengine

I have a qml file with `Rectangle`. I would like to trigger the `onClicked( )` from C++ back-end.
So, How can I get access of QML component reference in C++/Qt backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QObject::findChild()` to locate the object, and simply invoke the signal as you would a nominal method.

But there is a catch, as `QQuickRectangle` itself is a private class, so it is not directly available for use in the C++ API. Also, it doesn't really have a `clicked()` signal, not unless you implemented one yourself. And if you did, it won't be part of the C++ interface.

Also, there is no `onClicked()` signal, the signal is `clicked()` and `onClicked:` is the handler hook.

However, you can still emit it using the Qt meta system, just use:

```
QObject * object = engine.rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject *>("yourObjectName");
if (object) QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "clicked");
```

It will work even if the signal is implemented on the QML side, it will work even without casting to the concrete C++ type.

Now, if your object is not directly in the root object tree, you will not be able to find it and will have no choice but to pass a reference to it from the QML side to a C++ slot or invokable function.

Comment: I have tried to call the slot of QML onPropertyNameChanged() from invokeMethod, but it is not handling, I think,  signal can only be invoked.

Comment: @Ashif - there is no such object `onSignalName` - this is just an assist provided to make declarative connections, it cannot be invoked.